# Filter products that has n values in each rating using python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am working with Amazon reviews data and I am still learning about python and dataframes.

The df looks like this:

```
ID   Product_ID   Rating  reviewText
1    product_1    1       'ABC...
2    Product_1    1       'ABC...
3    Product_1    4       'ABC...
4    Product_1    5       'ABC...
5    Product_1    3       'ABC...
6    Product_2    3       'ABC...
7    Product_2    1       'ABC...
8    Product_2    1       'ABC...
9    Product_2    5       'ABC...
10   Product_2    2       'ABC...
11   Product_2    4       'ABC...
12   Product_2    4       'ABC...
.
.
.
```

I want to filter the products that have at least n reviews in each rating (rating is int from 1 to 5). For example, I want products that have at least 10 reviews per rating which means a total of 10*5 reviews.

The goal is to have a sufficient number of reviews in each rating per product. and later perform further NLP analysis.
and I've been stuck for two days trying to group them and using count but I can't get it right. any hint or help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, a few simple steps:

1. Get counts per product and rating

   ```
   reviews_per_rating = df[['Product_ID', 'Rating']].value_counts()
   ```
2. Check at least 5 per product

   ```
   select_product = (reviews_per_rating >= 10).groupby('Product_ID').all()
   ```
3. Now get the result as a list

   ```
   select_product = select_product.index[select_product].to_list()
   ```
4. And finally filter the products

   ```
   df.loc[df['Product_ID'].isin(select_product)]
   ```

Comment: How can I get the first 100 reviews per rating for each product? thanks in advance